# how to use contains when: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: python, pandas, contains

i like to do loop and check if cell contains "Ac" or "Vt string

that is my df

```
data={"col1":[2,3,4,5],
"col2":[4,2,4,6],
"col3":[7,6,9,11],
"col4":[14,11,22,8],
"name":["Acsd","Adgf","Vty","Acdf"],
"multi":[1.4,2.5,1.6,2.2]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

i try this :

```
for count1, i in enumerate(df["col1"]):
    if df.at[i, "name"].contains("Ac|Vt"):
        print("good")
```

and i got that error

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'**

how can i use contains that way?

Comment: `if 'A'  in df.at[i, "name"]:` ?

Comment: I just changed the condition in CONTIAINS
Anyway I got it 
KeyError: 4

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid using for loop altogether.

Why not just use `df["name"].str.contains("Ac|Vt")`?

You could add the result as a separate column too:

```py
df.loc[df["name"].str.contains("Ac|Vt"), "status"] = "good"
```

Comment: i need to do loop , but i can use this as a filter befor my loop

Answer (score 2):

Let's try using [`DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows),

```
for _, j in df.iterrows():
    if "Ac" in j['name'] or "Vt" in j['name']:
        print('Good')
```

Comment: That's the direction but I still need to use "enumerate"
like here "for count1, i in enumerate(df["col1"]):"

Comment: enumerate is not required here, ``iterrows`` return ``(index, Series)``

Answer (score 1):

No need to do in loop.

```
df.loc[(df.name.str.contains('Ac')|df.name.str.contains('Vt'))]
```

Comment: i need to do loop , but i can use this as a filter befor my loop

Comment: So does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly but it was useful